# Is this a justified expression for $\int \lfloor x^2 \rfloor \, \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

By observing patterns in Riemann sums for the following integral, I'm convinced that $$\int_0^\sqrt{n} \lfloor x^2 \rfloor \, \mathrm{d}x = (n-1)\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}-\sqrt{n-2}-\cdots-\sqrt{1},$$ with $n$ a positive integer. (We choose $\sqrt{n}$ as the upper limit because $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$ changes its $y$ at $x=\sqrt{n}$.)

Is this a correct assertion? Can this be used to find $\int_0^n \lfloor x^2 \rfloor \, \mathrm{d}x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's easier to just evaluate the integral directly, noting that there is a step at each square root of an integer:

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{n}} dx \, \lfloor x^2 \rfloor = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k \left ( \sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right)$$

The stated result follows from summation by parts:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k \left ( \sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right) = n \sqrt{n} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{k+1}$$

Comment: When you expand this sum, you get $(n-1)\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n-1} - \cdots - \sqrt1$ which is I'm pretty sure how OP got his formula.

Comment: sorry Ron , (+1) from me

Comment: @EricStucky: summation by parts.

Comment: @what'sup: no need to apologize.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int_0^\sqrt{n} \lfloor x^2 \rfloor \ dx   = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_\sqrt{k}^{\sqrt{k+1}} \lfloor x^2 \rfloor \ dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{\sqrt{k}}^{\sqrt{k+1}} k \ dx$$

write the terms sum and you'll know how it equals the integral

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k(\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k})   $$